# Custom classloader, JSP execution and resource retrieval inside webapp

Tags: java, jsp, classloader

Due project requirements, I need to create a webapp that, when executing, will allow some users to upload zip files which are like small apps and will contain .class files, resources (images, css, js, ...) and even lib files. That zip file is almost like a war file.

Any way to code it easily? AFAIK I think I know how to code the custom ClassLoader to load classes from inside the zip file ( [Java - Custom ClassLoader - trying to load a class using class file full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092550/java-custom-classloader-trying-to-load-a-class-using-class-file-full-path) ) and even code the resource retrieval when requested by the browser but no idea of how to execute JSP files which will be inside the zip file or load the jar lib files inside the zip file.

EDIT: the webapp must manage applications loaded, there is no way to implement this as answered below because the webapps need the "master" webapp to live. Also that "master" webapp allows versioning of applications. The user will be able to upload a new version and upgrade to it and even do a downgrade if the new version starts to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. It's a lot of work. Classloaders are very finicky beasts. Arguably the bulk of the work of creating something like Tomcat is wrangling the class loaders, the rest is just configuration. And even after all these years, we still have problems.

Tomcat, for example, is very aggressive on how it tries to unload existing webapps, using internal information of the Java class libraries to try and hunt down places for class loader leaks, etc. And despite their efforts, there's still problems.

The latest version of Glassfish has (or will have) the ability to version application deployments. You might have good luck simply hacking on Tomcats internal routing and mapping code to manage versioning.

If you're running an EJB container, you could put your core services in the EJBs and let the WARs talk to them (you could do this with web services in a generic servlet container, but many EJB containers can convert Remote semantics in to Local semantics for calls in to the same container).

You can also look at OSGI. That's another real pain to manage, but it might have enough granularity to even give you versioning, but none of your users will want to use it. Did I mention it's a real pain to manage? We do this for dynamic loading of web content and logic, but we don't version this.

If you must have everything under control of a single WAR, then your best bet is to punt on Java and instead use a scripting language. You tend to have a bit more control over the runtime of scripting environment, particularly if you DON'T let them access arbitrary Java classes.

With this you can upload whatever payload you want, handle all of the dispatch yourself to static resources and logic (which means you get to handle the versioning aspect). Use something like Velocity for your "JSP" pages, and then use Javascript or whatever for logic.

The versioned environment can be pain to pull off. If you don't care about doing it atomically, it's obviously easier. If you can afford "down time" (bring v1 offline then bring up v2), it's a lot easier. If you're uploading the full contents of each version, it's really easy. My system allowed incremental changes and had copy-on-write semantics, so it was a lot harder. But I didn't really want to upload several Gb of media for each version.

The basic takeaway is that when dealing with Classloaders, there be dragons -- nothing is easy with those and there are alternatives that actually get code in to production rather than creating scars and pissed off dragons. Using a scripting language simplifies that immensely. All the rest is dispatch, and that can be done with a filter or servlet.

You WILL get the great joy of reimplementing a solid chunk of the HTTP protocol doing this, that's always a treat as well since the servlet container doesn't really expose that functionality to you. That is, you'll want to do that if you want to be a good citizen on the web. You could always just continually shove content down the clients throat, caching and proxies be damned.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually create a WAR-like structures inside your web container webapps directory and put classes, JARs and JSPs there.

Given that hot redeployment is enabled in your web container it would automatically designate a separate classloader to this new web application that it finds.

In most cases web containers consider any folder having a WEB-INF subfolder containing a valid web.xml file to be a web application. You can restrict access to this new webapp by modifying its context configuration, located in META-INF/context.xml in case of Tomcat.

Controlling hot redeployment, classloader policies etc is dependent on the type of your web container, but I hope your is not worse than Tomcat which could handle all of that.